# Bind In and Out parameters on oracle procedure using typeorm

Tags: node.js, oracle, typescript, stored-procedures, typeorm

How to use typeorm to call a procedure with in and out parameters on oracle? I've tried to do this way but got the following error:

**Error: NJS-044: bind object must contain one of the following keys: "dir", "type", "maxSize", or "val"**

```
public async findOne(one: string) {
    try {
        const connection = await getConnection()
        const sql: string = `
        begin
        procedure(:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5);
        end;
       `;

const result: any = await connection.query(sql,[
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, type: oracledb.STRING, value: one },
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING },
    { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING },
  ]
);
    return Promise.resolve()
} catch (reason) {
    return Promise.reject(reason);
  }
}
```

Comment: Might help you ( look for procedure in the page), http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlproc

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 this page that you sent, in this case, would solve the problem using the oracledb driver, but i'm using typeorm on the database.